# Copy data from ArcGIS Online using Esri Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, esri-leaflet

I have an ArcGIS Pro level license with access to ArcGIS Online and need to automate the exports of data from ArcGIS Online, collected by field workers using Esri's Field Maps, to a file format that I can work with outside of ArcGIS (the goal is eventually to use it for reporting tasks) with Esri Leaflet. I've contacted Esri and the Technical Support individual I spoke with kept trying to lead me back to using Web App Builder to export data, but that doesn't really accomplish what I need to do. I need to automate that task, preferably with Leaflet if possible.

I've been working through resources on [this](https://developers.arcgis.com/esri-leaflet/query-and-edit/query-a-feature-layer-sql/) site and [this](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/querying-feature-layers-1.html) site, both of which discuss working with the attribute table, but I can't find any documentation on copying the data from the attribute tables to a separate file on my machine (or the machine of a coworker eventually).

Is there a way to use Leaflet to automate the export of data from a map layer store in AGOL to a CSV?

Comment: Do you have access to an ETL Tool?

Comment: My company doesn't utilize any, and I've never used any ETL tools outside of work. But if there are any affordable options (free, preferably) that would work for this purpose I will certainly look into it. Do you have any suggestions?